# Making dynamic filepaths for an exportable JAR file

Tags: java, file, dynamic, jar, path

I want to make a small, runnable program for my friends. As I am on a Mac and they mostly are running Windows, I have to make a **dynamic structure for the file paths (only images)** I am using in my program. Alas, here is my question:

**What is the easiest way to make dynamic file paths, so that my program can find the files no matter what computer (and OS) it is running on?**

Seeing as I have to export my program in a JAR file, the **images** will have to be **incorporated into the JAR file**.

**How is that possible?**

I have read about putting the files into the src folder of the program and creating a runnable JAR file, but it doesn't work... (Maybe because of my IDE? I am using Eclipse 4.13.0).

```
       try {
        File file = new File(".");
        String path = file.getCanonicalPath() + "/src";     // I put the img in the src folder of the program
        String newFile = path + "someImage.jpeg";
        BufferedImage myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(newFile));
        JLabel panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        c.add(panel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

This is working when running it in Eclipse, but not when running the runnable JAR file.

.
.
.

I am thankful for every answer and in the meantime will continue to search for answers on my own! :)

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you just want the images as resource files for your app. So, I would suggest the convenience of placing them inside the jar, out of sight from your clients (so long as you only just need to read them, a jar is read only.)

I am using Maven in my IDE ... so, the pom edit to tell the build to add these resources into the jar when the IDE builds it, is this:

```
<!-- AND THIS IS HOW YOU ADD YOUR OWN RESOURCES INTO THE JAR                                                                                                          
 -->            
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/resources/gum</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>**/*.txt</include>
              <include>**/*.jpg</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
```

See how I directed to be in my own special folder under /src ... yet in the jar, they appear at the root. I have to remember to preface my filenames now with an initial path separator, because I'm looking in a folder relative to the working directory the jvm is run from when working inside the jar.

And then, when you load resources out of a jar, you have to read the files using a little bit different structure than you do out on the normal file system. You load the resource as a stream, or it just throws an exception. Here's an example of how that might look for an image.

```
    java.awt.Image frameImage = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(
        getClass().getResource("/LotsaIcon.jpg")
    ).getImage();
    this.setIconImage(frameImage);
```

I hope any of this helps.

Edit: The reason it runs fine from the IDE, is the IDE doesn't actually run the jar, it runs the class files, and from a working directory somewhere in your IDE project, not the root of any executing jar.

Edit2: And did you say even an executable jar won't work? Or was it just the reading files part that failed? Because, as I do with Maven, you also have to tell the IDE you are wanting an executable jar, and I add pom edits for that too, to tell it the main class to add to the jar manifest it creates, or else it won't be an executable jar.

Comment: Hey man thanks for your quick answer! So I don't think I'm as advanced as you think I am. I don't know how the pom file is involved in building the .jar file and I don't know where to place it or even how to place it anywhere. Anyway, you helped me quite a lot in that I now know that I have to figure out how to create a pom file ;)

Comment: The pom file is the configuration, or build file, that Maven uses. You need to add entries to it to accomplish certain things, like dependencies, instructions about resources, and in this case, instructions about what your main class is etc etc for the runnable jar ... or to even tell it to make an executable jar. Every Maven project already has a pom.xml file that you edit and add your snippets to. Often, snippets you find on the internet that let's you include someones library in your Maven project. Research this pom.xml thing in Maven, it's how you tailor your project.